# Powershell script enhancements

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

We have 4 Hyper-V clusters, and I have created a script for powering on VM objects in those Hyper-V clusters.

The script is working fine, except that the script will only power on all VMs in the first cluster and not the following ones.

Is there any method to allow us to start the VMs simultaneously on multiple clusters.

```
$clusters = Get-Content "c:\temp\Clusters.txt"
foreach ($clu in $clusters){
while($true)
{    
    write-host "Cluster VM resources bringing online  for cluster $clu" -ForegroundColor Green
    $c = Get-Cluster -name $clu | Get-ClusterResource | where { $_.Name -and $_.state -eq "offline"} 
    $count = $c.Length
    write-host "Current Count: $count" -ForegroundColor Green
    if ($count -eq 0){
        break
    }else{
        echo $c[0..5] |Start-ClusterResource -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        Start-Sleep 20
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Start-Job`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) to run a cmdlet or a script block in the background:

```
$clusters = Get-Content "c:\temp\Clusters.txt"
foreach ($clu in $clusters) {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        Get-Cluster -name $clu | Get-ClusterResource | where { $_.Name -and $_.state -eq "offline"} |ForEach-Object {
            $_ |Start-ClusterResource -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
        }
    }
}
```

This is not tested (I don't have a hyper-v cluster for testing available).

Comment: thank you for update but i want to start only 5 VM's at a time per cluster and  sleep for 20 seconds

is it possible

Comment: Then adapt the script to your needs. The principle is the same.

Comment: I had run the above script and following is output and none of the VM's are started.

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
117    Job117          BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...                      
119    Job119          BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...

Comment: To see results of yours jobs you must use receive-job